# html: how to create a toggle switch.I am using bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to create a toggle switch in my page.

I am using bootstrap4.

I could not find relevant solution.

Something i am looking like: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Can anyone guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know there is no switch button in bootstrap 4 documentation and looks like they have not did this yet but hopefully they will have this in the future.
But github have made their own switch button with bootstrap and you can get it [here](https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/#usage).

You can use include it in your project with cdn or download it with npm / yarn.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4- toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

if with npm

```
npm install bootstrap4-toggle
```

Yarn

```
yarn add bootstrap4-toggle
```

and you are all set and ready to use it!

Demo

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="lg">
```

Hope it help ya! Please let me know if it can work or not ya. I am also trying to find a solution for this also.

Comment: What do you mean by "GitHub have made their own switch button"? The project you linked seems to be a fork by some random guy of the old Bootstrap Toggle for Bootstrap 2, totally not related with GitHub

Comment: my bad, sorry for my bad explanation and thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 8):

In Bootstrap 5.2.3 you can use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#switches

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap 4.5 you can find a [toggle switch](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#switches).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" disabled id="customSwitch2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Disabled switch element</label>
</div>
```